# what is the name of the jquery pluigin used in this code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I found this code on a website.

It has tabs and images, once I clicked on the table it shows all images associated with this table.

Can anyone help me to find the name of the plugin used in this code?

And why it is not working successfully?

This is all the scripts on the page:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap JS form CDN -->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- jQuery sticky menu -->
<script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.sticky.js"></script>

<!-- jQuery easing -->
<script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.min.js"></script>

<!-- Main Script -->
<script src="js/main.js"></script>

<!-- Slider -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bxslider.min.js"></script>   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.slider.js"></script>

<div class="row">
    <div role="tabpanel">
        <ul class="product-tab" role="tablist" style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 0px;" >
            <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">New Products</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Best Seller </a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#Must" aria-controls="Must" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Must Have</a></li>
         </ul>
         <div class="tab-content">
             <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="home">
                 <div class="promo-area">
                     <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6" style="padding-right:1px;padding-left:1px">
                         <div class="single-promo promo1">
                             <a href="single.html">
                                 <img src="http://store.storeimages.cdn-apple.com/4973/as-images.apple.com/is/image/AppleInc/aos/published/images/S/1/S1/42/S1-42-alu-silver-sport-white-grid?wid=332&hei=392&fmt=jpeg&qlt=95&op_sharpen=0&resMode=bicub&op_usm=0.5,0.5,0,0&iccEmbed=0&layer=comp&.v=1472247758975" width="100%" height="200px" style="padding:0px 5px" alt="Slide">
                             </a>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6" style="padding-right:1px;padding-left:1px">
                         <div class="single-promo promo2">
                             <a href="single.html">
                                 <img src="http://store.storeimages.cdn-apple.com/4973/as-images.apple.com/is/image/AppleInc/aos/published/images/a/pp/apple/tv/apple-tv-hero-select-201510?wid=538&hei=535&fmt=jpeg&qlt=95&op_sharpen=0&resMode=bicub&op_usm=0.5,0.5,0,0&iccEmbed=0&layer=comp&.v=vWwkV0" width="100%" height="200px" style="padding:0px 5px" alt="Slide">
                             </a>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6" style="padding-right:1px;padding-left:1px">
                         <div class="single-promo promo3">
                             <a href="single.html">
                                 <img src="img/Music/Bose/bsm51_1.jpg" width="100%" height="200px" style="padding:0px 5px" alt="Slide">
                             </a>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6" style="padding-right:1px;padding-left:1px">
                         <div class="single-promo promo4">
                             <a href="single.html">
                                 <img src="img/Accessories/laut/la71_1.jpg" width="100%" height="200px" style="padding:0px 5px">
                             </a>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
             <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="profile">
                 <div class="submit-review">
                     <div class="promo-area">
                         <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6" style="padding-right:1px;padding-left:1px">
                             <div class="single-promo promo1">
                                 <a href="single.html">
                                     <img src="http://cdn.bit68.com/tradeline/media/product_images/iPhone_6s_Space_Gray.jpg" alt="Slide" width="100%" height="100%" style="padding:0px 5px">
                                 </a>
                             </div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6" style="padding-right:1px;padding-left:1px">
                             <div class="single-promo promo2">
                                 <a href="single.html">
                                     <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSGWpLZhKGrzAHe2i2xG48uTO99bARgaLym8Q-HtymrFsuNfufoSw" alt="Slide" width="100%" height="100%" style="padding:0px 5px">
                                 </a>
                             </div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6" style="padding-right:1px;padding-left:1px">
                             <div class="single-promo promo3">
                                 <a href="single.html">
                                     <img src="img/Music/beats/bm44_1.jpg" alt="Slide" width="100%" height="100%" style="padding:0px 5px">
                                 </a>
                             </div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6" style="padding-right:1px;padding-left:1px">
                             <div class="single-promo promo4">
                                 <a href="single.html">
                                     <img src="img/Accessories/ozaki/oc6_1.jpg" alt="Slide" width="100%" height="100%" style="padding:0px 5px">
                                 </a>
                             </div>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
             <div role="Offers" class="tab-pane fade" id="Offers">
                 <div class="submit-review">
                     <div class="promo-area">
                         <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6" style="padding-right:1px;padding-left:1px">
                             <div class="single-promo promo1">
                                 <a href="single.html">
                                     <img src="img/image_01.png" alt="Slide" width="100%" height="100%" style="padding:0px 5px" >
                                 </a>
                             </div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6" style="padding-right:1px;padding-left:1px">
                             <div class="single-promo promo2">
                                 <a href="single.html">
                                     <img src="img/image_02.png" alt="Slide" width="100%" height="100%" style="padding:0px 5px">
                                 </a>
                             </div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6" style="padding-right:1px;padding-left:1px">
                             <div class="single-promo promo3">
                                 <a href="single.html">
                                     <img src="img/image_03.png" alt="Slide" width="100%" height="100%" style="padding:0px 5px">
                                 </a>
                             </div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6" style="padding-right:1px;padding-left:1px">
                             <div class="single-promo promo4">
                                 <a href="single.html">
                                     <img src="img/image_04.png" alt="Slide" width="100%" height="100%" style="padding:0px 5px">
                                 </a>
                             </div>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
             <div role="Must" class="tab-pane fade" id="Must">
                 <div class="submit-review">
                     <div class="promo-area">
                         <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6" style="padding-right:1px;padding-left:1px">
                             <div class="single-promo promo1">
                                 <a href="single.html">
                                     <img src="img/image_01.png" alt="Slide" width="100%" height="100%" style="padding:0px 5px">
                                 </a>
                             </div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6" style="padding-right:1px;padding-left:1px">
                             <div class="single-promo promo2">
                                 <a href="single.html">
                                     <img src="img/image_02.png" alt="Slide" width="100%" height="100%" style="padding:0px 5px">
                                 </a>
                             </div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6" style="padding-right:1px;padding-left:1px">
                             <div class="single-promo promo3">
                                 <a href="single.html">
                                     <img src="img/image_03.png" alt="Slide" width="100%" height="100%" style="padding:0px 5px">
                                 </a>
                             </div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6" style="padding-right:1px;padding-left:1px">
                             <div class="single-promo promo4">
                                 <a href="single.html">
                                     <img src="img/image_04.png" alt="Slide" width="100%" height="100%" style="padding:0px 5px">
                                 </a>
                             </div>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>            
 </div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand your question. I don't see any javascript or jquery. Can you post the script tags please?

Comment: Looks like a tool called bxslider.  Look here: http://bxslider.com/

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in your question. You can see the scripts that are imported at the beginning of the code

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap JS form CDN -->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- jQuery sticky menu -->
<script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.sticky.js"></script>

<!-- jQuery easing -->
<script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.min.js"></script>

<!-- Main Script -->
<script src="js/main.js"></script>

<!-- Slider -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bxslider.min.js"></script>   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.slider.js"></script>
```

It can be `owl.carousel` + `jquery.easing` + `bxslider`

Google those library and see if it is what you want. They may also have added some custom Javascript (Certainly in `main.js`)